# How to ensure/determine that a post is coming from an specific application running on an iPhone/iTouch?

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications

Building an iPhone OS application that will allow users to anonymously post information to a web application (in my particular case it will be a Rails based site) ... and I want to ensure that I only accept posts that originate from a specific application running on an iPhone/iTouch.

How is this best accomplished?

(btw, if your answer applies to Android please feel free to post it here as well as I'm curious to know if the techniques are the same or vary).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to implement a known call and response pattern. Send a value of some sort (integer, string, hash of a timestamp) to the iPhone/iTouch application. Have the application modify this information in a known way and send it back for verification. Then all you have to do is use a different modification algorithm per-platform and that will verify what type of device is being used.

VERY simple example:

1. Server sends `100` with the response to an iPhone.
2. iPhone adds `10` to this value and sends back with request.
3. Server detects the value was increased by `10` and now knows it was from an iPhone.

Then on your Android clients add `20` and on another platform add `30` and so on...

Comment: Even better would be to hide this data inconspicuously in a header and then validate against an explicit HTTP header like Jacob suggested to spot spoofing attempts.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is always the same data. This means the I could just record it and resend it from my bot that fakes requests to you rails site.

Comment: You don't use the same data though. Send the timestamp from the server with the response, cache it in the session, and then check the value from next request against it (i.e. if the client has added 1 year, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, and 1 second to it and then MD5'd it).

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a hidden field in the form. or in the data being passed up if it is XML or other format

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt or sign something using the public key of a key pair, then decrypt or verify it on the server with the private key.  Ultimately, anything that can be sent can be duplicated, be it a spoofed html header or an encrypted block.  The app has to know the secret handshake, and anyone with access to it (and sufficient technical skills) can figure out the secret handshake.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach.

Build an ssl enabled access to your rails app.
Now create a user account for every plattform you want to use and enable your applications to log in with the correct key. If you use the ssl standard in a correct way there shouldn't be a way to sniff the password and you can use standard components on the rail and the phone side of your app.

You then need to secure the login credentials on your phone with the appropriate technics. Eg. put it in the keychain on the Iphone.